# Multi-variate testing with custom form component

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

I have a custom form component that captures lead information and then gives the visitor a download.  I have set up an A/B test on the form with different fields and layout to determine which form is the most effective at capturing leads.  Basically our A case is the full form and the B case has only the required fields.

Until now both our A and B cases have a score of 0.  How do I measure success for a case of the multivariate test?  I imagine I need to trigger something in the code-behind that indicates a success or complete state but I don't have anything to go on. What am I missing either in the Page Editor/CMS side or on the code side? Or is this even possible?

Sitecore CMS 6.5.0 and DMS 2.0.0 rev.111230 (6.5.0 Update-3) - Not using WFM

Comment: Can you please provide the DMS version and WFM version? Also, have you read through how to set up MV testing in DMS? If not, you can refer to the Marketing Operations Cookbook on SDN: http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Reference/Sitecore%206/Marketing%20Operations%20Cookbook.aspx

Comment: Hi Adam, I updated the question... I'm using Sitecore CMS 6.5.0 and DMS 2.0.0 rev.111230 (6.5.0 Update-3) - Not using WFM.  Yes, that is a great reference, I have used it to set up my test in the Content Editor and then start my test from the Page Editor.  Is WFM required for Multivariate testing on forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might not have 'deployed' your test? You need to go into the Marketing Center > Test Lab > find your test and then in the Review Tab there will be a 'Deploy' option.

When you're done with your test, you come back here and click 'End Test' in the same place.

[image]

Check out the marketing operations cookbook for more detail.

http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/marketing_operations_cookbook_sc65-usletter.pdf

Comment: Thanks Goose! I will give that a shot here in a bit.

Comment: No worries, hopefully that's all it was ;)

Comment: Yep, must have missed that part when going through the Page Editor or something.  It seems to be working now.

Comment: Clicking on "Test" in Page Editor automatically deploys the Test to "Deployed" state, which is a lot more helpful because everything can be done from there.